# Linq with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jslinq

i started work with LINQ in javascript using http://jslinq.codeplex.com/ where it is suggested to add package jslinq. I added it and started with following query

```
var exampleArray = JSLINQ(myList)
                   .Where(function(item){ return item.FirstName == "Chris"; })
                   .OrderBy(function(item) { return item.FirstName; })
                   .Select(function(item){ return item.FirstName; });
```

but while debugging, on first line (var exampleArray = JSLINQ(myList)) shown error like 'uncought reference error JSLINQ not defined'..
please inform me what i am missing.. i am completely new to this.. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have You added

```
  <SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/JSLinq.js"></SCRIPT>
```

before you call JSLINQ(myList) ?